# How to show difference between two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two databases, each containing a 'settings' table with the same structure like this.  (There are hundreds of rows, but this is an example.)

```
db1.settings                              db2.settings
+-------------------+-----------+        +-------------------+-----------+
| param             | value     |        | param             | value     |
+-------------------+-----------+        +-------------------+-----------+
| MinimalShotLength | 50        |        | MinimalShotLength | 30        |
| OneTemplate       | 0         |        | OneTemplate       | 0         |
| MP4Type           | Universal |        | MP4Type           | Universal |
| Mixdown002        | Default   |        | VideoDevice       | Aja       |
+-------------------+-----------+        +-------------------+-----------+
```

db1 may contain rows that are missing in db2 and vice-versa.  The rows are not in the same order.

I want to create a new table showing only the differences between the two like this:

```
+-------------------+-----------+------+
| param             | db1       | db2  |
+-------------------+-----------+------+
| MinimalShotLength | 50        | 30   |
| Mixdown002        | Default   | NULL |
| VideoDevice       | NULL      | Aja  |
+-------------------+-----------+------+
```

Is this possible in MySQL or do I need to do it in PHP?  The closest I could find was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/compare-differences-between-two-tables-in-mysql#950505), but that puts each param on a separate row so it's harder to read the output.

Comment: Must it be using SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL knows nothing about `FULL OUTER JOIN`, so

```
SELECT t0.param, t1.value, t2.value
FROM (SELECT param from db1.settings
          UNION
      SELECT param from db2.settings) t0
LEFT JOIN db1.settings t1 ON t0.param = t1.param
LEFT JOIN db2.settings t2 ON t0.param = t2.param
-- remove duplicates if not need in
WHERE NOT (t1.value <=> t2.value)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start!  But in both examples, it does not remove rows where the param/value is equal between the two tables.

Comment: *it does not remove rows where the param/value is equal between the two tables.* Well, I'll edit... wait. Done.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  One small detail is I will edit the first line `t1.value as db1, t2.value as db2` to show column names